# JSONata returns Stack Overflow error when using functions on a non-first property in a new grouped object

Tags: stack-overflow, tail-recursion, jsonata

I am unsure if this stems from JSONata 2.0.0 but I have yet to see this from previous uses of this query language. I have a list of objects that the sub-arrays will contain the same dates:

```
{
property1: {
  subProperty1: [{"date": 1/1/2022, value: 10}...],
  subProperty2: [{"date": 1/1/2022, value: 50}...]
}
}
```

I am trying to create a new object where all values with the same date are summed together. When I believe I got the right query, I get a Stack Overflow recursion error. After more testing, it seems that a function called on the first property will work but any property after that will not have a working function. How or why is there a recursion on any non-first property and what in my code would cause a non-terminating loop?

[image: Date first, value listed]

[image: Date first, value error]

[image: Value first, date listed]

[image: Value first, date error]

I have tried creating an object of only the {date, value} object without adding any other properties. I am working on a direct line of $.*.*.* to see if I could diagnose any syntax errors on my part. The [value != null] is there to weed out null values that would stop a $sum() function from happening.

After changing the playground to 1.8.6, it is clear that 2.0.0 is why there is an issue.
[image: JSONata 1.8.6 works]

Comment: Adding a link to your Github issue in case it's addressed there and not here -- so other people can find it in the future : https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/606

Comment: Thank you for posting my question from the GitHub location, I didn't remember to do that.

Comment: Can you post the original data and expression as text (see request on Github issue) @JesseBenjaminSlomowitz